# Ler arquivos em python

Tags: python, sistema-de-arquivos

bom... eu tenho um arquivo com as seguintes coisas :

```
if
else
(
)
'
"
print
```

e o seguinte codigo :

```
arq = open('system/commands.txt','r')
arquivo = arq.readlines()
for l in range(0,7):
    print(arquivo[l])

palavra = input('Digite a palavra : ')

if palavra == arquivo[l]:
    print('certo !')
```

e queria saber como eu faço quando eu digitar a palavra que está escrita no arquivo ele aparecer o print('certo'),
no caso o comando acima nao está funcionando e queria saber o por que !

o comando vai até a parte do input depois não acontece nada

Comment: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7, é inclusivo o 0 do range, fica esperto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema está relacionado com a sua variável `l`; Ela é definida pelo `for`:

```
for l in range(0,7):
    print(arquivo[l])
```

Quando este `for` executa, a variável `l` vai incrementando de `0` a `6` e o `print` vai imprimir as 7 linhas do arquivo na tela. Em seguida, a variável `l` usada no `for` **ficará com o último valor que ela assumiu**, ou seja, `6`.

Continuando o programa, mais abaixo você faz uma comparação:

```
if palavra == arquivo[l]:
```

Esta linha está comparando a palavra digitada com a sétima palavra da lista `arquivo`, pois o valor de `l` é `6`, que é o valor que ficou de sobra nesta variável ao terminar o `for` acima;

Ou seja, `arquivo[l]` é equivalente a `arquivo[6]` (pois o valor de `l` neste ponto é `6`) o que é uma referência à palavra `"print"`.

Se você digitar a palavra `print`, vai receber a mensagem `certo`; caso digite qualquer outra coisa não vai receber nenhuma mensagem.

Comment: Funcionou, mas no caso como eu faria para ele ler todos as palavras do arquivo e se for igual ele executa o print?

Comment: @HyPe para isso você teria que comparar com todas as palavras do arquivo, e não só com uma; Existem várias formas de fazer isso, uma delas seria colocar a comparação dentro do `for`, outra seria usar o operador `in`, etc